# PageMethod wont fire when data is included in call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a basic function in my C# code behind on an ASP.NET page. It takes a string (which I will have formatted as a JSON object) and returns a string.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string TestPageMethod(string json)
    {
        return json;
    }
```

My javascript is as follows:

```
var updateUserLocationsJson = "{\"test\",123}";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../Manager/AddEditUser.aspx/TestPageMethod",
    data:updateUserLocationsJson,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

I can get the server side method to fire if I remove the string parameter from it and remove the data field from the javascript call.

I can also get the server-side method to fire if I call it using page methods i.e.

```
PageMethods.TestPageMethod("{\"test\",123}", PageMethodSuccess, PageMethodFail);
```

However I would like to get it to work using the $.ajax method while passing in data. I cannot figure out why it is not working. Can anybody shed some light on this please?

Comment: Try removing  the `contentType` field.

Comment: When I remove the contentType field it still doesn't fire. When I remove the contentType and dataType field it doesn't hit my method, but the success function is called. The msg parameter contains what appears to be the HTML of the page on which the javascript is called

Comment: Try changing contentType to `plain/text`.

Comment: No, still doesn't fire